# How to restore only a specific solution folder with an MSBuild command

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I have more than hundred projects in two solution folders.

How can I build a specific solution folder with the `msbuild` command in CLI, like the same thing in Visual Studio with right click on a specific solution folder and click on *Build*?

I use Visual Studio 2019 16.8.3

**Update:**

I found the *[Build a solution folder with MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6251099/1539100)* Stack Overflow question, but as you can see in this question, anyone does not provide a built-in solution for `restore` or `build` or any other target run in a specific solution folder. I hope to find a way to run the target on a specific solution folder with a built-in way using MSBuild.

Answer (score 0):

Just open **Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio** and then type these to build the specific .sln file like this:

```
msbuild xxx\xxx.sln -t:build -p:Configuration=Debug
```

The solution folder from **Solution Explorer** is a virtual folder for the Visual Studio IDE. If you want to use an MSBuild command line, you have to create such a real folder. Otherwise, there isn't any such way.

**1)** Open *Solution Explorer* → *Switch View*, create a real folder (on my side, it is called `test`), and then drag the related projects into the folder.

[image]

**2)** create a file called `test.proj` on the solution folder. And then add these on that file:

[image]

```
<Project>
    <ItemGroup>
        <File Include="test\**\*.csproj"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <MSBuild Projects="@(File)" Targets="Build"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

**3)** use command line `msbuild test.proj` to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want to specific solution folder, In one sln I have multiple solution folder, and I want to build only one of them

Comment: I think you have two folder which contains related different projects and you want to build one folder with the included projects,right?

Comment: Yes, but I have solution folder instead of real directory @Perry Qian-MSFT

Comment: I have updated my answer and you can check it.

Comment: Is there any CLI solution exist? or I have to write specific .proj for our task? why we cannot solution folder directly in CLI with msbuild, when SLN file has all information about solution folder? :(

Comment: I update my question. please see it, thanks

Comment: If you want to use cli with command line, the folder must be a real folder. Also, you can only use `msbuild SlnFolders.sln -target:test\ConsoleApp1:Rebuild` to build the project with the virtual folder. But you can only specify one project each and cannot specify a group projects in the folder. So as the link you searched, you have to create an own `proj` file or `sln` file to get what you want. The `sln` is ruleless and is more difficult to create such  one. So create a `proj` file is more easier. Add any projects that belongs to the virtual folder by `File Include="xxx.csproj"`.

Comment: Also, there is no such cli command line to once generate a custom `sln` file automatically based on the projects on the virtual folder. As I know, it is [dotnet sln add] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln). But is is suitable for new-sdk projects and only added one by one. The workload is the same as the `proj` file. So you have to try my function. And if you still want your idea, you should [suggest a feature to the Team](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=suggestion&space=8).